# How do i import a source code into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a folder called src and somehow i have to import it in to eclipse to work with the code.
This is how it comes from github:

[image]

I've tried to put the src folder in an existing project still cant read it. What should i do?
Im not so familiar with java :/
The final jar file stuctures should look like this:

[image]

(its a bukkit plugin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects`

And point it to the root folder of the projects (the one containing the top pom.xml).

You'll need a [Maven plugin for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) for this.

Comment: hmmm its worked until the server couldnt load it
[02:21:47 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\CustomItemsAPI.jar' in folder 'plugins
'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/go
ncalomb/bukkit/bkglib/bkgcommand/BKgCommand

Comment: is that an error when you start the project? it looks like your classpath is missing a jar with BKgCommand

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: right click on src -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder